# xtify 503 Rate Limit Exceeded

Tags: push, xtify

I'm sending push from my php server and I get the error 503 Rate Limit Exceeded.
I read in http://developer.xtify.com/display/APIs/Push+API+2.0 that "The default service limits you to 50 connections per IP address over 10 second period" but in another chat says that the limit is 5.
Which is correct? What are the limits?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The answer is: The default service limits you to 50 connections per IP address over 10 second period.